# Calling local api from real device failing (react-native-android)

Tags: react-native

```
signinFetch('http://192.xxx.x.x:8000/api/branch-api/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    grant_type: 'password',
    client_id: OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRECT,
    email: this.props.email,
    password: this.props.password,
    scope: ''
  })
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch((error) => {
   console.log(error);
});
```

can't call Login api from **physical device** to **local host**. But I can  *debug* the app on the *local host*, then why doesn't I am not getting response from local api

I have tried

Comment: Not enough information to make the diagnosis.. please share more information such error, environment, endpoint definition at the backend.. etc

Comment: No error messages, the request timed out after some time.                
Environment:  OS: Ubuntu 18.04    Node: 10.8.0   Yarn: Not Found    npm: 6.5.0 
  Watchman: Not Found    Android Studio: 3.2.1 Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338,  Didn't understand endpoint definition??

Comment: where the route is defined (branch-api/login)

Comment: routes is defined in _api.php_  .                                                                   
backend is laravel.                                                                                             
path to _api.php_ is  project/app/Modules/Api/Routes/api.php

Comment: Thanks for your help @RudolfCicko. I have found the solution. There is google documentation to do this by port forwarding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a google documentation to connect localhost to physical device [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server). Refer this,
it simple and easy